# 2-stable subsets of groups

Tags: group-theory

In this post, multiplication of subsets of a group is defined by
$$ST= \{st| s\in S, t \in T\}$$

> A subset of a group is called $n$-stable if there exists a natural number $n$ s.t. $$S = S\cdot \overbrace{S\cdot S\cdot S...}^{n \text{ times}}$$
> The minimal $n$ for which it’s true determines it’s name.

Does there exist a group who’s subset is 2-stable? i.e, $$S=SSS\neq SS$$
Of course, any singleton of a order 2 element suffices, but I’m looking for subsets of size 2 or more.
If we take a pair of elements $S=\{a,b\}$, $SS=\{a^2,ab,ba,b^2\}$...
Any help?

Comment: And you don't just want to take some subset $\{x^i\mid i\in I\}$ for some well-chosen subset $I$, where $G=\langle x\rangle$ is a cyclic group?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, Can you give an example?

Comment: $G=C_{10}$, $x$ has order $10$ in $G$, $S=\{x^i\mid i \in \{0,1,5,8\}\}$ was one I immediately found. It's just sets of numbers where sums of three of them form all classes modulo $n$ but sums of two of them don't.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, in your example, $SSS=G \neq S$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed what you wanted. I thought you wanted $G=SSS\neq SS$. Oh, that's much easier. Take all odd permutations in $S_n$. More generally, if $G\to C_2$ is any non-trivial homomorphism, take all elements not in the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $G=\langle S\rangle$. I claim that $S$ is $2$-stable if and only if there is an index-$2$ subgroup $H$ such that $S=G\setminus H$.

Suppose that $H$ has index $2$, and let $S=G\setminus H$. Certainly $SS=H$, and $SSS=HS=S$, and so the result holds in this case. Thus we need to establish the converse. Let $H$ denote the set of all even-length products of elements of $S$. This is a subgroup, since products of even-length products are even-length. We must prove that $H\cap S=\emptyset$, and then that $G\setminus H=S$. Notice that all odd-length products of elements of $S$ are elements of $S$.

Notice that this means that all even-length products appear in $SS$. If $t$ has even-length, then $t=s's$ for $s\in S$ and $s'$ of odd length, hence in $S$. Thus $G=S\cup SS$. But $SS$ is a subgroup, and therefore has at most half of the elements of $G$ in it. But it also has $Ss$ for a fixed $s\in S$ in it, and these must all be distinct. Thus $|S|=|SS|$ and $H$ has index $2$.

Comment: What does $\bar S$ mean?

Comment: It was a typo. In the first version I thought maybe you only had that $S$ was contained in $G\setminus H$. But since $S=SSS$ it must be equal.

Comment: Is $H =\ker \phi$

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying that $S$ has your property iff $S=G\setminus H$ for some index-$2$ subgroup $H$. I rewrote the answer and obviously didn't make it consistent.

Comment: it seems like your answer would work for any $n$, does it?

Comment: Yes, but you only asked for 2. :-)

Comment: Good enough, I understand how to generalize it.